# invalidate() doesn't take scroll position into account?

Tags: android, invalidation

In [source code of 2.3](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread-release/core/java/android/view/View.java), you can see the following code snippet in `invalidate()` :

```
    final Rect r = ai.mTmpInvalRect;
    r.set(0, 0, mRight - mLeft, mBottom - mTop);
    // Don't call invalidate -- we don't want to internally scroll
    // our own bounds
    p.invalidateChild(this, r);
```

That means this function doesn't take mScrollX/mScrollY into consideration.

While in `invalidate(int, int, int, int)`:

```
    final int scrollX = mScrollX;
    final int scrollY = mScrollY;
    final Rect tmpr = ai.mTmpInvalRect;
    tmpr.set(l - scrollX, t - scrollY, r - scrollX, b - scrollY);
    p.invalidateChild(this, tmpr);
```

It offsets the dirty region with current scroll position.

I write a simple test application and run it on android 2.3 using these two methods(`invalidate()` and `invalidate(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight())`) and the result is the same. So what does the pipeline do to make them the same effect?

Comment: Hi suitianshi can you help me with similar problem